# Django's cache framework not working in a Django-Celery application

Tags: python, django, caching, celery

I'm using Django + Celery to asynchronously process data.
Here is my settings.py:

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.locmem.LocMemCache',
    'LOCATION': 'unique-snowflake'
}
}
```

And here is my Celery task:

```
from celery import shared_task
from django.core.cache import cache

@shared_task
def process():
    my_data = cache.get('hello')
    if(my_data == None):
        my_data = 'something'
        cache.set('hello', my_data)
```

It's very simple. However, everytime I call the task, cache.get('hello') returns always None. I have no clu why. Someone could help me?

I also tried with Memcached and these settings:

```
> CACHES = {
>     'default': {
>         'BACKEND':
>         'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
>         'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
>         'TIMEOUT': 60 * 60 * 60 * 24,
>         'OPTIONS': {
>             'MAX_ENTRIES': 5000,
>         }
>     } }
```

Of course, memcached is running as daemon. But the code is still not working...

Comment: LocMemCache is storing results in memory and values are removed from it as soon as function finish execution. However, it shouldn't be an issue with Memcached. Try configuration without `TIMEOUT` and `OPTIONS`.

Comment: It works! Thank you.
Question is now, why TIMEOUT and OPTIONS make memcached not working anymore?